# How to get rid of eclipse random exceptions

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When i work on my project i sometimes get this random errors. When i run program a few more times it loads correctly. I am now on eclipse photon, i had the same issues on eclipse oxygen.3

starting with -clean dosen't help much. Even using new version of IDE dosen't help much...

I am using maven project.

And that classe that eclipse sometimes see missing is in .m2 folder of maven

How can i resolved this ?

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/SchedulerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplicationWithArgs$155(LauncherImpl.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.SchedulerException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 11 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:383)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    ... 5 more
```

Sometimes this

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:383)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    ... 5 more
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/SchedulerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplicationWithArgs$155(LauncherImpl.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.SchedulerException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 11 more
```

***Solution:***

Ok so i was diging a bit and i noticed that there is some problem with thread

```
com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

So i thought maybe maven project builder fights with java build builder and when i disabled "Maven Project Builder"in project properies in "Builders" tab it resolved problem. Now for a split secound some error occures but after that program starts normaly... stil i dont get why, but...

Comment: step 1: realize they're not "random". it would appear you are missing some dependencies

Comment: Are you sure you are loading all the relevant JARs that your application depends on? It seems that you are missing something from the `Quartz` scheduler.

Comment: @Stultuske that can't be the case(at least whole) because code compile, run and maven can build it without any error. Eclipse just 2 on 10 times has some problems.

Comment: @npinti i know that it looks like this but as i said everything is ok but not always...

Comment: It might be that some other process is still downloading the packages or else locks the files just when the build is taking place.

Comment: How can i debug it ? Code is not doing anything like this. And this error just started occure with out change to pom or build goals

Comment: "2 out of 10 times" when? When you start Eclipse, or after you recompile the project with maven, or after you do a random change triggering a recompile in Eclipse?

Comment: It is random but I 99% sure that never on first compilation and after first run it is very random. Sometimes 10 times i an row without any error and after that 6 times in a row with errors.